# Interpolation of loess.smooth in R

Tags: r, loess

I'm running a loess.smooth method after running the spline method on it.
The input given below is the data I get after running the spline method.
However I'm going wrong with the loess.smooth method. The entire first column is returning the output in float format but I need it in integer format with an increment of 1.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

```
**input:** spline_file
1   0.157587435
2   0.146704412
3   0.129899285
4   0.138925582
5   0.104085676

out <- loess.smooth(spline_file$x, spline_file$y, span = 1, degree = 1, 
family = c("gaussian"), length.out = seq(1, max_exp, by = 1), surface= 
"interpolate", normalize = TRUE, method="linear") 

**OUTPUT:**
0           0.150404703
1.020408163 0.154413716
2.040816327 0.158458172
3.06122449  0.162515428
4.081632653 0.166562839
5.102040816 0.170577762

**OUTPUT REQUIRED:**
x   y
1   0.225926707
2   0.226026551
3   0.226241194
4   0.2265471
5   0.226920733
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if the following fully answers your question but maybe it helps. Below some code, demonstrative plot and some explanations/recommendations.

1. You should not use a `degree` of 1, your data requires a higher degree.
2. You should check the allowed parameters via `?loess.smooth`. I think you mixed up some parameters of `scatter.smooth` and `loess.smooth` and further used some parameters that do not exist for the function (e.g. `normalize` - please correct me if I have overseen something).

In any case it makes sense that the output of a spline smoothing function has more data points than the original data. To be ablet to plot a smooth curve additional points are generated between your data points by the smoothing function. Check the plot generated at the end of below code. If the fit is good, is another question...

```
spline_file <- read.table(text = "
                   1   0.157587435
                   2   0.146704412
                   3   0.129899285
                   4   0.138925582
                   5   0.104085676
                   ", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(spline_file) <- c("x", "y")

spline_loess <- loess.smooth(spline_file$x, spline_file$y, span = 1, degree = 2, 
             family = c("gaussian")
             ,surface= "interpolate"
             , statistics = "exact"
             ) 

spline_loess
# $x
# [1] 1.000000 1.081633 1.163265 1.244898 1.326531 1.408163 1.489796
# [8] 1.571429 1.653061 1.734694 1.816327 1.897959 1.979592 2.061224
# [15] 2.142857 2.224490 2.306122 2.387755 2.469388 2.551020 2.632653
# [22] 2.714286 2.795918 2.877551 2.959184 3.040816 3.122449 3.204082
# [29] 3.285714 3.367347 3.448980 3.530612 3.612245 3.693878 3.775510
# [36] 3.857143 3.938776 4.020408 4.102041 4.183673 4.265306 4.346939
# [43] 4.428571 4.510204 4.591837 4.673469 4.755102 4.836735 4.918367
# [50] 5.000000
# 
# $y
# [1] 0.1586807 0.1571512 0.1556485 0.1541759 0.1527367 0.1513344
# [7] 0.1499721 0.1486533 0.1473813 0.1461595 0.1449911 0.1438795
# [13] 0.1428280 0.1417881 0.1406496 0.1394364 0.1381783 0.1369053
# [19] 0.1356473 0.1344341 0.1332957 0.1322619 0.1313626 0.1306278
# [25] 0.1300873 0.1297791 0.1297453 0.1299324 0.1302747 0.1307066
# [31] 0.1311626 0.1315769 0.1318839 0.1320181 0.1319138 0.1315054
# [37] 0.1307273 0.1295270 0.1281453 0.1266888 0.1251504 0.1235232
# [43] 0.1218002 0.1199744 0.1180388 0.1159866 0.1138105 0.1115038
# [49] 0.1090594 0.1064704

plot(spline_file)
lines(spline_loess)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the need to use a higher `degree`. Also your right about the `normalize` parameter, I seem to have mixed it up with `scatter.smooth`. I agree with you that additional points will be generated , the same also happened when I ran the `spline` method and I fixed it by passing the parameter with `xout = seq(0, 100, by = 1)` so even though additional points are generated they are within the range and are incremented by one.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issues or are there any open points? If it solved everything please consider accepting the answer or at least upvote it. Thanks. Otherwise I will try to answer any open issues.

Comment: No I'm sorry, I'm still having the same issues where the output is returning the same output in float format.

Comment: you cannot have only 5 integer values as output after smoothing, see my explanation. You might still pick the individual data points from your output were x equals your desired integer values and then use as.integer on x. does that help?

Comment: No I know I need to pass at least 50 integer values as output. Also I did try as.integer on x and it didn't work in the `loess.smooth` method.